# Training and Validation Accuracy in Tensorflow Object Detection API

Tags: python, object, tensorflow, detection

I have been using Tensorflow Object detection API on my own dataset. While training, the training losses are updated on the tensorboard. But I need the training and validation accuracy respectively (mAP). 
What steps need to be taken to get these values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the keras API, through `tf.keras`, you can add evaluation functions as metrics in the `model.fit` function. Checkout [the official documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics) for a list of all available metrics.

You might be interested be interested in [`tf.metrics.average_precision_at_k`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/metrics/average_precision_at_k). If it doesn't do exactly what you need, you can also implement a custom metric.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said mAP which stands for Mean Average Precision, you need to have the metrics_set in your pipeline config file with the value "coco_detection_metrics". Your file should have something like that:

```
    eval_config: {
        metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
        use_moving_averages: false
    }
```

After that, when you run the eval_continuously you should get the mAP on your validation set.
For the training set you need to set the `eval_on_train_data` parameter when running the `model_main_tf2.py` script.

Comment: The `model_main_tf2.py` script says that the `eval_on_train_data` option is only available in distributed training. Does that mean that I need multiple GPUs to use that option?